# where can I buy a whole bitcoin?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

I want to buy a full bitcoin at the current price. But coinbase only allows me to buy in $250 increments. Where can I go to purchase an entire bitcoin?

I would go to Localbitcoins.com but their fees are usually too high.

So what I need is a low fee way of buying an entire bitcoin.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the US, you can buy it on coinbase.com or https://exchange.gemini.com/

You need to buy some Bitcoins on coinbase, they will automatically increase your limit. I can buy $5000 worth of Bitcoins on Coinbase, and would if I had the money.

Fees of Gemini are low, ie .05 cents for $20 in BTC, or 50 cents for a $200 order.

Or localbitcoins, if you care about anonymity, but they charge a high markup.

Answer (score -2):

Try http://localbitcoins.com.

From the website:

> Buy and sell bitcoins near you
>   Instant. Secure. Private.
>   Trade bitcoins in 14431 cities and 248 countries including United States.

It does appear to require an account to be made, but it appears to be free.

Comment: Yeah I have. However their fees are usually too high. What I want is a low cost way of achieving this. I've edited the question to reflect that. Thanks

Comment: Yeah it's free. But if you notice the selling price for bitcoin by the sellers on that site is usually a lot higher than the regular price for BTC that you see on somewhere like coinbase. That's why I shy away from it. The markup from the sellers of bitcoin on this site is just too high usually. Still continuing to search. Thanks tho.